# Anychart - CSV to table

Tags: anychart

I am trying to create a chart using anystock that will read data from a csv file. Using the built in anychart.data.loadCsvFile function doesn't give me a working chart for a stock chart while it was working just fine for a line chart. I think I need the csv file to be loaded into a properly formatted table. Is there a function for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample how to do that, you can avoid creating table if the csv matches the series format and you have no need in mapping: http://jsfiddle.net/3vtszfx0/2/

```
anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {
    anychart.data.loadCsvFile('https://cdn.anychart.com/samples-data/stock-general-features/load-csv-data/data.csv', function (data) {
        // create stock chart
        chart = anychart.stock();

        // create plot
        var plot = chart.plot(0);
        // create column series on the first plot
        var column = plot.column(data);
        column.name('MSFT');

        // set container id for the chart
        chart.container('container');
        // initiate chart drawing
        chart.draw();

    });
});
```

If you need mapping then: http://jsfiddle.net/3vtszfx0/1/

```
    // create data table on loaded data
    var msftDataTable = anychart.data.table();
    msftDataTable.addData(data);
    mapping = msftDataTable.mapAs({'x': 0, 'value': 1});

    // create plot
    var plot = chart.plot(0);
    // create column series on the first plot
    var column = plot.column(mapping);
    column.name('MSFT');
```

Comment: Thank you!! I was confused about how to use the 'data' variable I guess.